# Unity 3D same method returns different values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

the method CurrentWeapon() when used in the first script it will return the value of the variable SelectedWeapon. but when i use it in the 2nd script it always returns the same value: Any way i can get the value of SelectedWeapon in the 2nd script every time it changes in the first one

```
 public class WeaponSwitching : MonoBehaviour {
    public int SelectedWeapon = 0;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() { SelectWeapon(); }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    Debug.Log("---"+CurrentWeapon());
    }
    
    public int CurrentWeapon()
    {
    return SelectedWeapon;
    }
```

the 2nd script:

```
public class GunController : MonoBehaviour {  
WeaponSwitching SelectedW = new WeaponSwitching();

private void Update()
{
Debug.Log(SelectedW.CurrentWeapon());
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the  `= new WeaponSwitching();` in the second script because you want to get the `SelectedWeapon` from the `WeaponSwitching` monobehaviour instance of your scene.

I think you should do:

```
public class GunController : MonoBehaviour {  
    public WeaponSwitching SelectedW; //not new, drag in this field in unity editor

    private void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(SelectedW.CurrentWeapon());
    }

}
```

To reference the class instance you want, so that you get the `SelectedWeapon` of that specific instance.

Also take into account that `Monobehaviours` should not be newed, because they "live" in a unity gameObject.